# How can we change data type of a data frame column from object to string in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I was taking all categorical variables using

```
numerical = map_quest._get_numeric_data().columns
categorical = list(set(map_quest.columns) - set(numerical))
```

Using this, the 'Description' column (which contains description of that particular record) is also getting considered as 'object' which I don't want. I don't want to drop Description either as I would like to use it for later purpose.

Is there any way we can convert 'Description' column to string?

Answer (score 0):

```
df.astype({"Description": str})
```

To answer the Tin Man's comment, [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) are the docs which answer all the questions brought up.

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Comment: @theTinMan The question merely asked for the how to do something, so I provided a built in function. I have edited the answer with a link to the pandas docs, which answer the questions you've brought up.

Comment: But still it would be considered as an object. Is there any way change that?